# Awk File processing to get last processed weekday

Tags: bash, awk, xml

My application which does processing based on input XML's, processes the input files and adds the status to status_file.txt after processing.

I am writing a script to identify the last processed day per XML file and to provide that as a input to another script.

I have two types of XML's deployed:

- 1. which supports weekend processing (`test2.xml`)
- 2. Which dont support weekend processing.(`test1.xml`)

Sample XML with Weekend processing Enabled - `test2.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Company>
  <Employee>
      <FirstName>Test</FirstName>
      <ContactNo>1234567890</ContactNo>
      <Address>
      <WeekendProcessing>True</WeekendProcessing>
      </Address>
  </Employee>
</Company>
```

Sample XML with Weekend processing Disabled - `test1.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Company>
  <Employee>
      <FirstName>Test</FirstName>
      <ContactNo>1234567890</ContactNo>
      <Address>
      <WeekendProcessing>False</WeekendProcessing>
      </Address>
  </Employee>
</Company>
```

Sample `status_file.txt`

```
INPUT_NAME1,INPUT_NAME2,Procecessed_DATE
test1.xml,AAAA,BBBB,20201024
test1.xml,AAAA,CCCC,20201025
test2.xml,AAAA,BBBB,20201024
test1.xml,EFGH,IJKL,20201023
test1.xml,AAAA,BBBB,20201024
test2.xml,AAAA,CCCC,20201021
test1.xml,AAAA,BBBB,20201022 
test2.xml,AAAA,BBBB,20201022
test1.xml,EFGH,IJKL,20201023
```

Below is the command I have tried to get the last processing day for the XML.

```
LPD=$(cat status_file.txt | grep <XML_NAME> | awk -F "," '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq)
```

**NOTE: Weekday here means Business days, fom Monday to Friday**

It works fine for XML thats supports weekend processing. But I am stuck in situation to identify the Last processed weekday for a XML that doesn't support weekend processing. Note: Even for weekday XML entry with weekend date will be present.

Also : I am unable to use the logic of sort and tail -2 as some times for weekend we may get more than 2 entries.

Expected reuslts:

```
# script <test1.xml> - I should get last processed weekday
O/p Required - 20201023
# script <test2.xml> - I should get last processed day either weekday/weekend
O/p Required - 20201025
```

Comment: Hi @thanasisp - I need to extract the last successful processed weekday for <WeekendProcessing>False xml.

Comment: Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/618368/edit) your question and add a representative `status_file.txt` with real filenames, the filename you want to look for, and the exact expected result.

Comment: @thanasisp- Could you please check is that clear.

Comment: So the output for test2 will be the latest date, 20201024?

Comment: Yes, thats correct and for test1 it should be 20201023.

Comment: Why not 20201025 for test1, which is more recent?

Comment: Because that is weekend. For test1 we need to find only last processed weekday. due to bug in application it adds weekend dates as well even though if it is not processing.

Comment: This is exactly the reason I suggested you to add `the exact expected result`. Currently your expected result is again a description, `# script <test1.xml> - I should get last processed weekday`, not a real file/command/text. Do you want for example to print `Monday`, `Friday` because this is the `weekday`, the weekday alone can have only 7 different values and does not contain the date, year-month-day etc. Furthermore, your issue seems to be just how to get the last date that it is not Saturday or Sunday (If I get it correctly).

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. This is first post, Made a note of the points to mention while posting the question. I have update the expected results now.

Comment: There is no problem at all. Defining problems is more difficult than solving them. I think there is a misunderstanding while translating `weekday` into your language. Let's clarify it: `weekday` contains all days, including Saturday and Sunday. So it is not the appropriate term here. I guess you mean the last processing date that was not Saturday or Sunday, right? So I see 2020-10-25 was Sunday, you don't want it, you get the last day 2020-10-23 which was valid, Friday.

Comment: Thats correct. Modifying it. thanks

Comment: The result for `test2.xml` is `20201024`, my script says, it seems it's correct, that's the max value in your input for `test2.xml` (and weekend True)

Comment: Your question still doesn't say what you want to do. (It does say what you've tried, but it doesn't explain the desired target.) There are bits of clarification in the comments but I'm not sure which have been changed over time. Could you please put your requirement into the question itself

Comment: @roaima i have highlighted the expected result, could you please check now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU `awk` and some help from `xmllint` to parse the xml.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

input_file="$1"
status_file="status_file.txt"

weekend="True"
weekend="$(xmllint --xpath "//WeekendProcessing/text()" "$1")"

awk -F, -v f="$input_file" -v weekend="$weekend" '
$1 == f && $NF > max {
    if (weekend == "True") {
        max = $NF
    } else {
        d = mktime(substr($NF,1,4)" "substr($NF,5,2)" "substr($NF,7)" 00 00 00")
        if (strftime("%u",d) < 6) max = $NF
    }
}
END {print max}
' "$status_file"
```

Testing:

```
> bash test.sh test1.xml
20201023
> bash test.sh test2.xml
20201024
```

Notes:

- I used `xmllint` to extract the text value of `WeekendProseccing` node with a single path selection. You could replace it with your favourite way to get a value from an xml file.
- We do not sort the lines, we parse once the file, it is also faster. We don't call external date commands. For `weekend="True"`, we keep the maximum date. Or else, for `weekend="False"`, we use the [GNU awk datetime functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html). We create the date with `mktime()` and we test the weekday with `strftime()` using format: `%u` which returns a number in the range 1-7 (1 for Monday). So we update the maximum only if the higher date found is not Saturday or Sunday.

Comment: Thank you so much it works!!!!!!!

Comment: my server does not have --xpath option. i am getting uknown option. Is there any other options. Could you plz suggest.

Comment: Use whtever is available to get the text vlue of a simple XML node. If you have `xmllint` availble, `xmllint --help` to see. You coull also have `xml` (=`xmlstarlet`), `xpath` or anyhting else. You already process xml so you certainly have available software for xml parsing.